# NSArray unrecognized what I put inside it and give me error

Tags: php, iphone, ios, nsarray, json

I am using NSArray and putting inside it the string that I retrieve using `json_encode`
it works when it plain text , but not working if it like in my image and giving me this error

[image]

i also tried to use NSMutableArray but the same problem, so if is the problem from these "\r\n" .. etc , how to convert it to plain text ?

and here is the code that i use :

```
NSError *er;
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/ost.php"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    content = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:&er];
    NSLog(@"%@",json_string);     
NSLog(@"%d",[content count]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[content objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: Where's the code? This looks like a memory related issue.

Comment: {
    0 = " :
\n
\n<a title=\"http://www.mediafire.com/?qp0srwq71lccsx1\" href=\"http://www.mediafire.com/?qp0srwq71lccsx1\">http://www.mediafire.com/?qp0srwq71lccsx1</a>
\n
\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rU9RXYeeR_A";
    "post_content" = "\U0644\U062a\U062d\U0645\U064a\U0644 \U0645\U0644\U0641\U0627\U062a \U0627\U0644\U0628\U0631\U0646\U0627\U0645\U062c :
\n
\n<a title=\"http://www.mediafire.com/?qp0srwq71lccsx1\" href=\"http://www.mediafire.com/?qp0srwq71lccsx1\">http://www.mediafire.com/?qp0srwq71lccsx1</a>
\n
\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rU9RXYeeR_A";
}

Comment: dear its not the valid json you can check your jason with jsonlint.com

Answer (score 4):

I see an NSDictinoary error, which uses `objectForKey` rather than `objectAtIndex`

Your problem is likely:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[content objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Check the type of `content` It's likely a dictionary that's being asked for object at index.

Comment: This is definitely the reason for the error in the log. Even if OP is using NSArray for the json string, there is a NSDictionary which is causing the issue somewhere.

Comment: but i am not using any NSDictionary, i am just using nsarry .

Comment: the third line in your log is clearly an NSDictionary being asked for objectAtIndex "unrecognized selector sent to instance variable..."

Comment: yeah i can see it , but  I am sure that no use for NSDictionary.

Comment: You are using a dictionary. You're sure otherwise, but you're still *wrong*.

Comment: try logging NSLog(@"%@",content)

Comment: yes , it is work with this command but giving me like the string above @Eric

Comment: this line: `content = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:&er];` is returning an `NSDictionary`, not an `NSArray`, most likely.